# Rendering User ID ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

Currently using mongoose to render admin and user information on a dashboard however i can't seem to render the id of a user

Here is my code

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
  } else {
    req.flash('error_msg', 'You are not logged in');
    res.redirect('/dashboard/login');
  }
}

/* GET Dashboard page. */
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    res.render('dashboard/index.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
      total: users.length,
      users: users
    });
  });
});
```

```
<a href="/dashboard/users/{{_id}}">My profile</a>
```

Added some code to the question from the repo. Added the ensureAuthenticated function. From what I can see the model and everything is setup correctly and as an example the *total* renders correctly so it a getting *users*.

Comment: Your view gets `users` - you are accessing `user`. Is your example coding missing a loop or is that a mistake?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen All I am trying to do is render a user details when they login to a dashboard, so no loop is needed because I am trying to render one users information

Comment: Sure :) But still, in your controller/route you set `      users: users    ` and in your view/template you are accessing `user` - they are two different variable names

Comment: @JoelPeltonen even if you set users:users as user:user you get the same result

Comment: Can you share a little more of the code? Also I just noticed you are using .id, but mongo IDs are often `_id` so maybe try with the underscore as well. And if you do `user:user` in your controller, the result form `User.find()` is always going to be an array, so I don't actually advise you doing that. My point was more the point you in the direction of thinking about the data types of your variables :)

Comment: Like; if you have a user authenticating middleware you might be missing something like `user: req.user` from the variables you are giving to whatever templating thing that is

Comment: @JoelPeltonen I’ve added some more code including the authentication. I have tested this on a previous app and it does work successfully so not sure exactly what is missing here.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to me that there simply isn't any place where the `user` variable is getting any value - if you don't actually have a user, you can't refer to it.

Comment: Does this happen to be an open source project? If so, I'd be interested in seeing the repository

Comment: @JoelPeltonen It's not open source but I can send you an invite if you wish

Comment: Cool - if it's on github I am https://github.com/Req

Comment: @JoelPeltonen i have invited you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you debug the `req` that you have, something (I suspect Passport) has included a user variable directly there, so you can feed that into your view.

```
/* GET Dashboard page. */
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    res.render('dashboard/index.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
      total: users.length,
      users: users,
      currentUser: req.user
    });
  });
});
```

And in your view you can use that

```
<a href="/dashboard/users/{{currentUser._id}}">My profile</a>
```

Comment: Thank you this works, something must have changed in passport that affects the users render